# LinkedIn OAuth2 with spring-security-oauth2-client not working, client_id missing when requesting accessToken

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, spring-security-oauth2

The spring-security-oauth2-client provides the means to easily integrate foreign services with my application. It has built-in support for authentication with Google, Facebook, Github & Okta, but also supports the registration of other oauth2 providers. In this case I'm trying to add LinkedIn as a provider, which works great up until my application tries to make the POST-request to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken .

For this request to succeed it requires the **client_id** & **client_secret** to be added as **parameters**. But this isn't the way spring-security-oauth2-client is built, because all of the other providers require the **client_id** & **client_secret** to be added as an encoded string in the **request headers**.

Because of this LinkedIn returns a 401 saying it's missing my **client_id**. You can view my configuration of the LinkedIn provider down below:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.provider=linkedin
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.client-id=MYID
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.client-secret=MYSECRET
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.scope=MYSCOPES
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.client-name=linkedin login
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.redirect-uri-template=http://MYWEBSITE/login/oauth2/code/linkedin
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.client-authentication-method=form

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.linkedin.authorization-uri=https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.linkedin.token-uri=https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.linkedin.user-info-uri=https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me
```

Trying this configuration with Github's credentials and url's resulted in my website successfully receiving an accessToken from Github.

Is there any way to configure this package to work with LinkedIn? Or is there any possibile way that LinkedIn might allow the **client_id** & **client_secret** in the headers of the POST-request to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the setting `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.linkedin.client-authentication-method=form`, I was unable to make the correct request to LinkedIn. The setting `form` was not supported by my version of spring-security-oauth2-client (5.0.6.RELEASE). After changing it to `post` it worked like a charm, but then I encountered the next problem which I'm going to ask about in another question.

The question for my newly encountered troubles: [LinkedIn OAuth2 /accessToken response not return a "token_type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745792/linkedin-oauth2-accesstoken-response-not-return-a-token-type)