# LinkedIn OAuth2 /oauth/v2/accessToken response not returning a "token_type"

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, access-token, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using spring-security-oauth2-client for the authentication in my project, but the library expects a "token_type" to be present in the response of the POST-request to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken. The library is built following the OAuth2 convention, but LinkedIn is not following this convention. The AccessToken convention: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.1

Does anyone have a fix for this problem? I temporarily cloned one of the child libraries of spring-security-oauth2-client to force the "token_type" to be "Bearer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has already been reported [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5983) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8598). The fix proposed [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5983#issuecomment-431076600) by [jgrandja](https://github.com/jgrandja) is working.